# Rails, RefineryCMS, can I still create custom controllers, models, etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I want to continue to create rails controllers and models as I would using rails directly.

Is it possible to have the site use the CMS except on specific objects I want to create the normal Rails way or do I have push all my code through Refinery and use decorators for development?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You have multiple options here. Among them:

- Create pure vanilla Ruby on Rails components.
- Copy and edit some RefineryCMS files. The local copy will override the one in the gem.
- You can also create presentors and decorators
- Create an extension to RefineryCMS.